# Javascript: Why does execution context default to global or window for standalone functions?

Tags: javascript

In the code below:

```
var x = {
    y: function() {
        console.log(this === global); // false
        function z() {
            console.log(this === global); // true
        };
        z();
    }
};

x.y();
```

When you call `y`, you are providing the execution context of x. As such `this` is the x object.

Why is the execution context of `z` the global object (or window object in a browser)?

It seems like it would be impossible to create a different execution context for `z` in the way it is defined. i.e. `this.z()`, `global.z()`, `x.z()`, `y.z()` all error with the message that there is no `z` function in that execution context.

For this reason, is it true to say that functions defined in the form `function name() {}` are **ALWAYS** defined in the global object's execution context? AND that unless call/bind/apply are used to invoke the function, execution is ALSO ALWAYS in the global object context?

**Question**: why does a function in this form `function name() ...` get defined in the global context and not the context of the object it is written in?

---

The above is in response to this article: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

"What if we just call a normal, everyday function...

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function test_this() { 
   return this; 
  } 
  var i_wonder_what_this_is = test_this(); 
 </script>
```

In this case, we weren’t provided a context by new, nor were we given a context in the form of an object to piggyback off of. Here, this defaults to reference the most global thing it can: for web pages, this is the window object."

Comment: where do you get `global` from?

Comment: What is a "call site"? You might want to read [MDN's article about how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: `this` depends on *how you call the function.* The difference is precisely in `x.y` vs. just `z`.

Comment: @deceze I have edited the question, the intention was not to ask about the `this` object, but how `function name() ...` definitions are treated

Comment: Functions aren't "defined" within any context (only *literal scope*, but that's a slightly different topic). The context, i.e. what `this` refers to, is decided at call time and purely by *how you call* the function. So, yes, a `function foo` can only be called as `foo()`, so will by default have the global object as `this`. That is, unless you reassign it; e.g. `this.foo = foo; this.foo()`... **Call time** matters, not declaration.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess my question is where can I find out more about how `function name()...` declarations are actually handled. Is this a question regarding how the Javascript engine works?

Comment: Except for hoisting behaviour, `function foo ..` is exactly equivalent to `var foo = function ..`. There's nothing else special about it.